# If someone with luck is lucky, someone with chutzpah is

Tags: tenses, yiddish

What so you call someone with chutzpah? If someone who has strength is strong and someone who has luck is lucky, what is someone who has chutzpah?

There's lots of almost-there synonyms, eg brave, impudent, audatious, cheeky, but the gulf between the meaning of those words shows the subtlety and breadth of "chutzpah". Is there a form of that word that works in this context?

Comment: Audacious is the closest one I know of. I'm not aware of any adjectives derived from the Yiddish, unfortunately.

Comment: Undoubtedly, *chapatti*.

Comment: I would say "insolent".

Comment: 'Fills a much needed gap in the lexicon'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it - its chutzpahdik! Thanks to John Clifford for pointing me in the right direction.  http://jewishquestions.bjpa.org/Questions/details.cfm?QuestionID=11853

Answer (score 1):

Ballsy, in common parlance. While this is of course slang and carries sexist overtones, it captures the subtle connotation of maybe straddling the line between courageous in a good way vs audacious in perhaps an inappropriate or offputting way.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ballsy

http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/15011?redirectedFrom=ballsy#eid

```
determined and courageous, plucky, spirited; (also) masculine; virile, aggressive.
```

Answer (score -2):

We try 'Gutsy ' as in got lots of guts .Guts is similar to Balls.In a sentence :That neuted lawyer did not have the Guts to stand up to the Feminazi family court judge .

Comment: Feminazi? Really? You're on the wrong site. The one you're after is spelled 4 c h a n.

Comment: *Gutsy* is a valid answer, but you might want to consider a less inflammatory example sentence (and possibly a dictionary citation, which might include suitable examples).

Comment: I was using an old word in a modern slang context.The old word nazi has modern meaning .It means staunch , Strict ,Accurate.What I was saying was that the judge was better than the lawyer .I will try to do a sentence .When you rebuild an engine you have to be national socialist about the ring clearances .In other words if you even get it slightly wrong it will end in tears.

Comment: Ha ha ha ha nope.